# Error while using Case when Alias in join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT T1.COL1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T1.COL2 = 111
            THEN 'A'
        WHEN T1.COL2 = 222
            THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'C'
        END AS DT
    ,T2.COL1
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COL1 = DT;
```

error-  invalid identifier  DT

I want to use and verify the condition using case when alias in join condition which is giving error

NOTE - UPDATED CODE

```
SELECT T1.COL1
        ,CASE 
            WHEN T1.COL2 = 111
                THEN 'A'
            WHEN T1.COL2 = 222
                THEN 'B'
            ELSE 'C'
            END AS DT
        ,T2.COL1
    FROM TABLE1 T1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COL1 = CASE 
            WHEN T1.COL2 = 111
                THEN 'A'
            WHEN T1.COL2 = 222
                THEN 'B'
            ELSE 'C'
            END;
```

THis one is working. Any other way other than this?

Comment: `DT` is not there you are declaring `DT` as an alias, when you are trying to join already existing table with `DT` (which is not present atm) it won't find any column with `DT`

Comment: How to satisfy this condition then. I want to check the join condition on the case statement result and table 1 column

Comment: Verify your condition AFTER the keyword "WHERE" and use the "LEFT JOIN" properly. I guess you should replace "ON T1.COL1 = Ta.COLX".

Comment: "ON T1.COL1 = Ta.COLX"

Didnt got you. Ta.COLX?

Comment: This join makes 0 sense to me.. You are joining t1 and t2 but not using any values from t2 in join statement. i.e. you are saying join t1 with t2 where t1.col1 is a or b or c (and this values are gained from t1.col2). which would just make cross join using rows from t1 whose col1 matches A or B OR C. Could you provide sample data and expected results?

Comment: You would like to dive deeper into subquerying

Comment: The JOIN logically occurs BEFORE the case expression is evaluated. See [logical processing order](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/11/18/sql-server-logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement/). So it is quite simply impossible to use a case expression as a column in the SELECT list and reference it in a join within the same scope of the same query. There are ways around that. For future reference, "giving error" and similar phrases are never useful to write. Always provide the complete and exact error message.

Comment: "... LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COL1 = T2.COLUMNX" Where "COLUMNX" is the field where both tables join! Note tha it cannot be a CASE, it MUST be a field existing in "T2".

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your new query still makes no sense. As noted previously, your join does not involve any column from TABLE2. Perhaps you obfuscated table names to the point you added this logic error by accident? Here is one way to avoid the huge effort to copy/paste the case expression code.

```
with cte as (
   select *, 
   case COL2 
        when 111 then 'A' 
        when 222 then 'B' 
        else 'C' end as DT
   from dbo.TABLE1 
)
select ... 
  from cte left join dbo.TABLE2 as t2
    on cte.Col1 = cte.DT
order by ... ;
```

If this case expression is commonly used, you could create a computed column and use it for your "join". That does not address the logic flaw but does address reusability.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the assembly of the custom column in a table expression, then the new column gets *officially* named and can be used on any other expression.

For example:

```
select t1.*, T2.COL1
from ( -- this is a "table expression" named "t1"
  SELECT T1.COL1
    ,CASE 
        WHEN T1.COL2 = 111
            THEN 'A'
        WHEN T1.COL2 = 222
            THEN 'B'
        ELSE 'C'
        END AS DT
  FROM TABLE1
) t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.COL1 = t1.DT;
```